# How to implement __init_subclass__ magic method properly?

Tags: python

I've created a base class:

```
class BaseNewAdapter:

    def __init_subclass__(cls, /, base_url: str) -> None:
        cls._base_url = base_url
```

But PyCharm gives me a warning:

> Signature of method 'BaseNewAdapter.**init_subclass**()' does not
> match signature of the base method in class 'object'

[image]

For me it seems the code is ok. What's wrong?

Comment: False positive. Your code is fine.

Comment: The bug report was filed 5 years ago: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-31529/Inspection-raises-signature-mismatch-on-overridden-args-kwargs-base-method